# How to bind the resort child of vBox in javafx and jfxml

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, vbox

I have the folloing fxml code which includes grid pane and vbox which includes buttons with its ids

is it possible to bind vbox so that the order of the buttons are resorted based on the fx:id?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<GridPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="472.0" prefWidth="698.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/18">
  <columnConstraints>
    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
  </columnConstraints>
  <rowConstraints>
    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
  </rowConstraints>
   <children>
      <VBox prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" GridPane.columnIndex="1">
         <children>
            <Button fx:id="1" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="72.0" prefWidth="350.0" text="1" />
            <Button fx:id="2" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="72.0" prefWidth="350.0" text="2" />
            <Button fx:id="3" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="72.0" prefWidth="350.0" text="3" />
            <Button fx:id="4" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="72.0" prefWidth="350.0" text="4" />
            <Button fx:id="5" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="72.0" prefWidth="350.0" text="5" />
            <Button fx:id="6" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="72.0" prefWidth="350.0" text="6" />
            <Button fx:id="7" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="72.0" prefWidth="350.0" text="7" />
         </children>
      </VBox>
   </children>
</GridPane>
```

> The Controller
> the controller has

```
        @FXML
            public void initialize() {
List<Integer> ids = new ArrayList<>();        // resort the childs of vbox based on the list "ids"
    
    }
```

i want to bind the list of buttons to my "ids" variable which includes the new fx-id`s and if the order of list-elemens changes then the order of list of buttons inside vbox should also be changed

Comment: don't quite understand the problem - just add some code that sorts the children by id? and what do you mean by _bind_?

Comment: @Abra 
thanks will edit the post, my main target is if i change the order ids inside "ids" then the vbox will change the order of its childs as will.

Comment: That seems complicated. If you simply reorder the `<Button>` elements in the FXML file, then they will be in that new order inside the `VBox`. Could you explain why you want to tie this order to the `fx:id` values?

Comment: @Slaw i want to bind the list of buttons to my "ids" variable which includes the new fx-id`s and if the order of  list-elemens changes then the order of list of buttons inside vbox should also be changed

Comment: In that case, it may make more sense to not declare the `Button`s inside FXML. Create them in the controller so that you can easily map them to the corresponding data (this will also be more dynamic in terms of the number of buttons). Add a listener to the backing data (I assume you're using something like an `ObservableList` or added your own observer API). In that listener, reorder the buttons as needed.

Comment: @Slaw thanks you understand my problem perfectly, can you give me some code snippet for that please?

Comment: I'm not convinced that changing the layout on the fly is the best option.  Assuming that there's nothing awesomely complex about the button designs, just treat them like a List of generic triggers.  Create a list of StringProperties and bind each Button's TextProperty to the corresponding StringProperty in the List.  Then manipulate the List's StringProperties and the Button labels will follow.  Have each Button call some method passing it's index, and it can figure out what to do.

Answer (score 0):

0
Better use TreeMap from SortedMap interface.

```
SortedMap<Integer, CheckBox> sm = TreeMap<Integer, CheckBox>();

sm.put(new Integer(1),new CheckBox("first checkbox"));
sm.put(new Integer(2),new CheckBox("second checkbox"));
sm.put(new Integer(3),new CheckBox("third checkbox"));
sm.put(new Integer(4),new CheckBox("fourth checkbox"));
sm.put(new Integer(5),new CheckBox("fifth checkbox"));
sm.put(new Integer(6),new CheckBox("sixth checkbox"));
sm.put(new Integer(7),new CheckBox("seventh checkbox"));
....
```

getting them after traversing in the order of the id